# load openssl RSA key from a string in C

Tags: c, openssl, pem

I'm having a little trouble understanding what function to use to load my key into an RSA.

I get the key in string form like this from a local database:

> -----begin public key----- migfma0gcsqgsib3dqebaquaa4gnadcbiqkbgqdcz4npasjgxrcv8fwqcrdw+cze
>   76l3inzil3mquizvuyyn5heqqsrvg7/4mu1czc5fghcuk2pbfjgk9ev3xz6soxpk
>   pkhkxot87xgkmi1hulszcyouhvrtgkgcbk/kuktqozklgbolxf+cxigdptpgareg
>   dp+6ieuziwsfpjrkjwidaqab
>   -----end public key-----

then I try something like this (in objective-c):

```
long len = [key length];
const unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)[key UTF8String];
RSA *r = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, &p, len);
```

r always comes back null so I'm doing something wrong there.  I've tried a few other things but I'm just missing it I guess.  The ultimate goal is to create an RSA from my public key, and then use something like

```
RSA_public_encrypt ( 1, hash,    secret,     r, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING );
```

To encrypt a hash, but I'm stuck on loading my keys :)  Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to use `ERR_get_error()` to obtaion information about OpenSSL error.

Comment: thank you, I get error number 218529960 which google tells me means asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

Answer (score 3):

After a day of banging my head against the wall I finally found the solution.  It didn't help that I had accidentally lower cased the key when I stored it...

Anyway here's what I did, assuming your key is in a NSString called key this code will load it for you.

```
const char *p = (char *)[key UTF8String];

BIO *bufio;
RSA *rsa;
NSUInteger byteCount = [key lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

bufio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)p, byteCount);
RSA *myRSA = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(bufio, 0, 0, 0);
```